# How can I archive someone's Facebook profile page?

Tags: wget, curl, facebook

I thought about using archive.is or archive.org. I tried to view the page in a private browser, but it asks to log in, so that site will see the same thing.

I tried to open the developer console and 'copy command as curl', but curl doesn't have recursive download for images and stylesheets like `wget` does.

I tried to 'save as HAR with content', but it saved a `.har` file and there doesn't seem to be any file associations for that to view it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Method 1: Text Archive

**Step 1:** Go to the page.

**Step 2:** Hit `CTRL+A` and then copy the text `CTRL+C`.

**Step 3:** Open a Rich Text editor, like OpenOffice Write.

**Step 4:** Paste the text `CTRL+V`.

**Step 5:** Repeat steps 3 and 4 with different editors until a more perfect result is achieved.

## Method 2: Snapshots

Install a Full Page screenshot extension, such as [Full Page Screen Capture](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/full-page-screen-capture/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl) for Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

to download someone's facebook page go to `httrack.com` and download. it will download entire web page.